# cannot display work orders in an email

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-views, sendmail, manytomanyfield

Hello I am trying to display work orders from my mysql database to show up in an email. However There is a problem because work_orders is a part of my Class Invoice manytomany field. This gives me this error.

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'description'
```

I not really sure what the problem is. Here are some part of my app that could be helpful.

```
#views.py
@login_required
def invoice_mail(request, id=1):
    invoices_list = Invoice.objects.filter(pk=id)
    invoice = get_object_or_404(Invoice, pk=id)
    client = invoices_list[0].client
    invoice_no = invoices_list[0].invoice_no
    date = invoices_list[0].date
    work_orders = invoices_list[0].work_orders
    t = loader.get_template('registration/email.txt')
    c = Context({
    'client': client.company,
    'address':client.address,
    'city': client.city,
    'postcode': client.postcode,
    'email': client.email,
    'date': date,
    'invoice_no': invoice_no,
    'work_orders': work_orders.description,
    })
    send_mail('Welcome to My Project', t.render(c), 'jess@example.com', ['tom@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
    return render_to_response('sent_email.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))


email.txt

INVOICE


Bill to:                            INVOICE # {{invoice_no}}
{{client}}                          DATE: {{date}}
{{address}}
{{city}}
{{postcode}}
{{email}}

quantity item Description
              {{work_orders.description}}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get invoices_list[0].work_orders.description?

Comment: Something like that yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you added a description field to the manager, the attribute doesn't exist (as it says).
Maybe you want to use

```
for order in work_orders.all():
    print order.description
```

or in a template

```
{% for order in work_orders.all }}
    {{ order.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

And maybe you need to change it in the context

```
'work_orders': work_orders
```

Comment: The only probelm I am having is it I am not using a standard html template. I am using a text document because tags do not work in an email.

Comment: Actually after typing the views part of the code, it has actually worked ;).

Answer (score 1):

`work_orders` is not a list. It's an accessor/ORM Manager for your many-to-many field.

To get the actual work orders, you need to do `work_orders.all()` (or `.filter(foo=bar)`) and then iterate over each work order you get back to format them decently for including in an email